# Why is Hibernate 5 not respecting my @Column name?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

For my JPA entities I always annotate everything with `@Table` and `@Column` I don't want Hibernate to guess what the name of a table or column should be. I want Hibernate to use what is in my code.

I had an entity with the following field mapping

```
@Column(name = "isPrimary")
private Boolean isPrimary;
```

With Hibernate 4.x generated sql queries would list the column name as `isprimary` however when I upgraded my app to use SpringBoot 1.4 from a traditional .war without SpringBoot. Hibernate 5 started using `is_primary` as the column names in the queries that it generated which caused an exception because the database column is called `isprimary` not `is_primary`

I changed my `@Column(name = "isPrimary")` to `@Column(name = "isprimary")` and Hibernate 5 went back to generating the column name correctly.

My understanding of JPA is that if you set `@Column` then the JPA provider should respect that and not mess with the name in the annotation.

- Is my understanding of JPA correct?
- Why is Hibernate changing the name?

Comment: check naming strategy , this interface usually is the solution for such issues

Comment: Your understanding of the JPA spec is correct. If Hibernate frigs about with the name even when you have specified it then Hibernate has an "issue"

Answer (score 1):

Starting from **Spring Boot 1.4**, because of the switch to Hibernate 5, 
the naming strategy has been updated to SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy which should be very close to 1.3 defaults.

SpringNamingStrategy is no longer used as Hibernate 5.1 has removed support for the old NamingStrategy interface. A new SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy is now auto-configured which is used in combination with Hibernate’s default ImplicitNamingStrategy. This should be very close to (if not identical) to Spring Boot 1.3 defaults, however, you should check your Database schema is correct when upgrading.

[For More Details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#naming-strategy)